# The right ID is not stored in session php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a page with vacancies where people can react on.

I am loading the data for the vacancies from dynamic op my page. I want to store the id of the vacancies that I selected in a session so I can use it on the page for reactions. This I want to do because I need to get the right reaction by the right vacancy.

But my problem is that the session I have created always gets the vacancy id 18 from my database and not the id from the right vacancy that I had selected.

PHP code for loading the vacancies dynamic:

```
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
 //include '../loginHandlerconnect.php';
    //include('php/loginHandlerconnect.php');

    //$db = loginHandlerconnect();

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM vacature ORDER BY datum DESC'; 
    $results = $db->query($sql);

    foreach($results as $row) 
    {           
        $id = $row['vacatureID'];
        $werkgeverid = $row['werkgeverID'];
        $functie = $row['functie'];
        $vacatureDatum = $row['datum'];
        $vacatureDatum = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($vacatureDatum)); // $vacatureDatum omdraaien van Y-m-d naar d-m-Y
        $omschrijvingkort = $row['omschrijvingKort'];
        $omschrijving = $row['omschrijving'];

        $_SESSION[$id]['vvacatureid'] = $id;
        $_SESSION[$id]['vwerkgeverid'] = $werkgeverid;
        $_SESSION[$id]['vfunctie'] = $functie;
        $_SESSION[$id]['vdatum'] = $vacatureDatum;
        $_SESSION[$id]['vomschrijvingkort'] = $omschrijvingkort;

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM werkgever WHERE werkgeverID = '. $werkgeverid .' LIMIT 1';

        $results = $db->query($sql);
        foreach($results as $row) 
        {  
            $bedrijfimage = $row['image'];
            $bedrijfnaam = $row['naamBedrijf'];
            $plaats = $row['plaats'];
            $provincie = $row['provincie'];

            $_SESSION['vomschrijving'] = $omschrijving;
            $_SESSION['vimage'] = $bedrijfimage;
            $_SESSION['vnaambedrijf'] = $bedrijfnaam;
            $_SESSION['vplaats'] = $plaats;
            $_SESSION['vprovincie'] = $provincie;
        } 
        //$string = strip_tags($string);

        if (strlen($functie) > 20) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut = substr($functie, 0, 20);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $functie = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
        }
        if (strlen($bedrijfnaam) > 25) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut2 = substr($bedrijfnaam, 0, 14);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $bedrijfnaam = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
        }
        if (strlen($omschrijvingkort) > 63) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut2 = substr($omschrijvingkort, 0, 63);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $omschrijvingkort = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
        }

        echo 
        "
            <div class='vacatureinfo2'>
                <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $bedrijfimage ."' id='imge'/>
                <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $functie ." - ". $bedrijfnaam ." - ". $plaats ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $vacatureDatum ."</p>
                <div class='omschrijvingkort2'>
                    ". $omschrijvingkort ."
                </div>
                <p class='pull-right'><a href='reactie?id=" . $id . "'>Reageer</a> | <a href='informatie-vacature'>Meer informatie</a></p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        ";
    } 



//echo "<div id='weergavebericht'></div>";
?>
```

PHP code for the reaction:

```
    <?php 
session_start();
/*
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
*/

include("loginHandlerconnect.php");

// variables voor datum/tijd en werkgeverID aanmaken zodat deze in de sql query meegenomen kunnen worden.
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam"); //tijdzone voor goede tijdsweergave
$datum = date("d-m-Y");
$tijd = date("h:i:s");
$id = $_SESSION['werknemerid'];
$vid = $_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vvacatureid'];
$functie = $_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vfunctie'];
$omschrijving = $_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vomschrijving'];
// functie om te kijken of de variabelen niet leeg zijn.
function checkEmpty($datum, $id, $vid, $functie, $omschrijving, $tijd) 
{   
    $datumcheck = $datum;
    $tijdcheck = $tijd;
    $werknemercheck = $id;
    $vacaturecheck = $vid;
    $functiecheck = $functie;
    $omschrijvingcheck = $omschrijving;
    $motivatiecheck = $_POST['motivatie'];


    if (empty($datumcheck) || empty($tijdcheck) || empty($werknemercheck) || empty($vacaturecheck) || empty($functiecheck) || empty($omschrijvingcheck) || empty($motivatiecheck))
    {
        echo "empty box";
        return 2;   
    }
}
checkEmpty($datum, $id, $vid, $functie, $omschrijving, $tijd);

// functie om data naar database te schrijven.
function loginHandlerEstab ($datum, $id, $vid, $tijd)
{
    $db = loginHandlerconnect();
    $werknemerid = $db->quote($id);
    $vacatureid = $db->quote($vid);
    $date = $db->quote(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datum)));
    $time = $db->quote(date('h:i:s', strtotime($tijd)));
    $motivatie = $db->quote($_POST['motivatie']);

    $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO reactie(werknemerID, vacatureID, datum, tijd, motivatie) VALUES(' . $werknemerid . ', ' . $vacatureid . ', '. $date .', '. $time .', ' . $motivatie . ')';
    //$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO vacature(werkgeverID, datum, functie, omschrijvingKort, omschrijving, isActief) VALUES(1, 'DATE()', 'beveiliger', 'beveiliger gezocht', 'beveiliger gezocht voor in de avonden', 1)';
    $db->exec($sql2);

    $_SESSION['motivatie'] = $_POST['motivatie'];

    //header('Location: ../geplaatst');
    echo $sql2;
    var_dump($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vvacatureid']);
    var_dump($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vfunctie']);
    var_dump($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vomschrijving']);

}
loginHandlerEstab($datum, $id, $vid, $tijd);

// als er een veld lee is gelaten wordt de error message emptybox opgeroepen.
if (checkEmpty($datum, $id, $vid, $functie, $omschrijving, $tijd) == 2)
{
    //header('Location: ../reactie?error=emptybox');        
}

?>
```

Does somebody know how to fix my problem?

UPDATE:

reaction form:

```
        <?php include("includes/header.php");
session_start(); 

if ($_SESSION['werknemerid'] == true){


if (isset($_GET['error'])){
    if ($_GET['error'] == "emptybox"){
        echo "<script>alert('U heeft iets niet ingevuld, kunt u dit even nakijken?');</script>";    
    }
}

include("php/loginHandlerconnect.php");
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");

?>

        <div class="page-header">
            <div>
                <h1>Reactie plaatsen</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap6">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="php/reactiewerknemer.php">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php 
                    var_dump($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vvacatureid']);
                    var_dump($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vfunctie']);
                    var_dump($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vomschrijving']);
                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datum">Datum van plaatsing</label>
                        <p><?php echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s"); echo " " . $_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['v']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datum">Functie</label>
                        <p><?php echo $_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vfunctie']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datum">Omschrijving</label>
                        <p><?php echo $_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['vomschrijving']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="motivatie">Motivatie</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control ckeditor" type="text" name="motivatie" id="motivatie" rows="5" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['motivatie']) ? $_POST['motivatie'] : ""); ?>"required><?php echo (isset($_POST['motivatie']) ? $_POST['motivatie'] : ""); ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" name="plaats" id="plaats">Plaats reactie</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php include("includes/footer.php");
}
else{
    header('Location: ../loginerror');
}?>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {        
        CKEDITOR.instances.motivatie.on( 'key', function() {
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances.motivatie.getData();
            if (str.length > 493) {
                CKEDITOR.instances.motivatie.setData(str.substring(0, 993));
            }
        } );
    };
</script>
```

Comment: ... Where are you "selecting" the vaccine id? Because as far as I can see, you are setting the id `$id = $row['vacatureID'];` here, in a foreach loop, without making it a array or any form of check, which means that the last value to run through the loop is the one stored.

Comment: @Epodax Oke thanks so I need to set the sessions after my foreach loop?

Comment: @Epodax oke I have tried that but it still doesn't work. I have set all my sessions after the closing tagg } from my first foreach loop.... (my variable names are in dutch :P)

Comment: In the `echo" ";` from the code from vacancy (at the end of the code) I let the vacancy show and store the id from that vacancy in `<p hidden>". $id ."</p>`... and in the code for reaction I set the `$_SESSION['vvacatureid'];` (who I created in the code for vacancy) to `$vid` and the `$vid` I use in my sql query.

Comment: @Epodax oke and how do I do that?

Comment: There are multiple ways of passing the variable to the next page, since you are using a link you could do something like: <a href='reactie&vacatureid=$id'>Reageer</a> depending on you using a htaccess you could simplify this by saying <a href='reactie/$id'>Reageer</a> Then the only thing you need to do is get the 'vacature' again on the other page based on the id.. If possible, feel free to take the discussion to the chat..

Comment: Sorry @Marjolein there's just too many possibilities for your code failing and without having better options of debugging I can't help you.

Comment: @Epodax thanks anyway for trying to help me!

Comment: @Marjolein As I said before, If we could move this discussion to the chat, I would be more than welcome to help, but right now spamming comments isn't getting anyone anywhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code, I don't know if this is a school project or for a genuine business, but I would recommend rewriting the code.. Preferably have a look at object oriented coding or at least split all your work up in different functions.

That being said, some hints:

It looks like you are first getting all vacatures from the database, and then adding the correct werkgever to each record.
This can easily be done within one query, saving a lot of foreaches:

```
SELECT vacatures.*, werkgever.image,werkgever.plaats, werkgever.provincie, werkgever.naamBedrijf FROM vacatures LEFT JOIN werkgever ON (werkgever.werkgeverID = vacatures.werkgeverID)
```

now you have all vacatures with company details.

```
$_SESSION[$id]['vvacatureid'] = $id;
```

Is outside of the foreach loop you created, so it will always contain the last result of that foreach loop.

I will add some rewriting here later for you.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
    include('php/loginHandlerconnect.php');


    $db = loginHandlerconnect();
    $sql = 'SELECT vacatures.*, werkgever.image, werkgever.plaats, werkgever.provincie, werkgever.naamBedrijf  FROM vacatures LEFT JOIN werkgever ON (vacatures.werkgeverID = werkgever.werkgeverID)'; 
    $results = $db->query($sql);


    /*
    * Nu hebben we een resultset met de volgende data per row
    * vacatureID
    * werkgeverID
    * functie
    * datum
    * omschrijvingKort
    * omschrijving
    * image (werkgever)
    * plaats (werkgever)
    * provincie (werkgever)
    * naamBedrijf (werkgever)
    */
    foreach($results as $row) 
    {           
       //Clean record
        cleanRecord($row);
        echo generateDiv($row);
    } 


//echo "<div id='weergavebericht'></div>";

/**
* Not a fan of this function, but I´m not going to rewrite these, for now it will work for you
**/
function cleanRecord($row)
{
     if (strlen($row['functie']) > 20) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut = substr($row['functie'], 0, 20);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $row['functie'] = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
        }
        if (strlen($row['naamBedrijf']) > 25) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut2 = substr($row['naamBedrijf'], 0, 14);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $row['naamBedrijf'] = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
        }
        if (strlen($row['omschrijvingKort']) > 63) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut2 = substr($row['omschrijvingKort'], 0, 63);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $row['omschrijvingKort'] = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
        }

        return $row;
}
    function generateDiv($row)
    {
        $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['datum']));
        return "
            <div class='vacatureinfo2'>
                <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $row['image'] ."' id='imge'/>
                <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $row['functie'] ." - ". $row['naamBedrijf'] ." - ". $row['plaats'] ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $data ."</p>
                <div class='omschrijvingkort2'>
                    ". $row['omschrijvingKort'] ."
                </div>
                <p class='pull-right'><a href='reactie?id=" . $row['vacatureID'] . "'>Reageer</a> | <a href='informatie-vacature'>Meer informatie</a></p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        ";
    }
?>
```

You don´t need to set all variables into the SESSION, you get the id on the next page, and can just run the query again to load the correct vacature data.

Comment: oops, wrong variable name, fixed it, can you try again?

Comment: its hard for me to test, i have changed one more thing, can you retry? do you get any error messages?

Comment: missing semicolon.. chage this:

$row = cleanRecord($row)
Into this:
$row = cleanRecord($row);

it would be easier if you enable error_reporting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91750/discussion-between-thomas-lang-and-marjolein).